# regexp - to break a line into words

Tags: regex

i'm working for a long time to get an regexp string - but without any success.
Hope, to get some help here.
There are strings in the following format:

```
G/20/EU (picture)/europe 21/
```

or

```
/House/200 hits/real estate
```

or

```
color/red-green/dark blue/orange/321
```

Global rule: split the text on the characters / ( )
So the following regexp works: ([/()])
But I also need to remove/split on single numbers. Here: 20 and 321, but NOT on 21 (which is one phrase with "europe 21") or 200 (which is one phrase with "200 hits")

Sometimes the strings starts with an / or ends with an /, sometimes not. Numbers can occur at the beginning, at the end or in the middle of the string.

The results should be simple words or phrases like:

```
G
EU
picture
europe 21
House
200 hits
real estate
color
red-green
dark blue
orange
```

Have anyone an idea, how an regexp could look like?

Thank you

Comment: For each of your examples, would you show the correct split result?

Comment: Also, which flavor of regex are you using? Perl, PHP, C#, JavaScript, Java, ..., ... Different flavors have different capabilities (negative lookbehind, etc.).

Comment: Which language are you using? I don't see a problem with the numbers... could you elaborate on that?

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, @Felix Kling this expression will run in solr/lucene. Probably java will execute that.  I will update the answer for example results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your regex flavour does have look ahead and behind, you can try this:

```
[/()]|(?<=\/|^)\d+(?=(?:\/|$))
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2u2pc).

This will check for a series of digits, where there is a `/` or the start of the row `^` before, and a `/` or the end of the row `$` behind.
Or for your part

Comment: same like the expression from @searlea - it works great. But it lookes more complicated!? Maybe you consider more
variations with your solution?

Comment: @The Bndr, I would say its more advanced. If you understand what the lookbehind and lookahead are doing, then its in my opinion more clear than having a longer list of alternatives.

Comment: @The Bndr, you can simplify the solution from @searlea to `(^|\/)\d+(\/|$)|[/()]`. The difference between this and mine is: here those characters are matched, with the look arounds it is just checked if they are there, but they are not matched. [See Regexr](http://regexr.com?2u2pi)

Comment: "If you understand what the lookbehind and lookahead are doing" no, i don't understand. It seems, your solution handles each "tokenizer" separately, while the solution from @searlea handles the tokenizer as an group!? Finlay the solution from @searlea is "more clear" for my horizon of knowledge. So I'm able to expand this. At your solution, I don't relay know, what I'm doing there! ;-) It seems, you have amazing knowledge in Regex... I think, I will take the solution from @searlea with your simplification.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly this:

```
/^\d+\/|\/\d+\/|\/\d+$|\//
```

i.e. check for number at start of string, or number between two slashes or number at end of string, or just a slash on it's own...

Comment: thank you :-) - that means in combination with "my" part the regexp at all lookes like that: /^\d+\/|\/\d+\/|\/\d+$|\//|[/()]

Answer (score 0):

Providing I've understood the example, the regex below should give the required output.

```
void Main()
{
    string testString = @"G/20/EU (picture)/europe 21/";

    Regex test = new Regex(@"(\w+[^\w\d]?|\d+)/");

    string outputTest = test.Replace(testString, "$1\r\n");

    Console.WriteLine(outputTest);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With (G)Awk, you can do something like:

```
awk -F "[()/]" '{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if ($i !~ /^[0-9]*$/ ) {print $i }}}' <<EOF
G/20/EU (picture)/europe 21/
/House/200 hits/real estate
color/red-green/dark blue/orange/321
EOF
#OUTPUT:
G
EU 
picture
europe 21
House
200 hits
real estate
color
red-green
dark blue
orange
```

Or see at: http://ideone.com/2f7lJ

HTH